# Estimates involving sums with binomials

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

When calculating some probabilities, I got sums of the form
$$\sum_{j=0}^c {j+a+b \choose a} p^j,$$ for integers $a, b, c > 0$.

Does someone know closed forms for these values?

Comment: It can be expressed in terms of hypergeometric functions according to *Mathematica*, but I doubt you'd want that closed form.

Comment: Do you need a fast algorithm to compute these, Or do you absolutely need a closed form? Are there any constraints on a? b,c?

Comment: @J. Mangaldan: correct. Thanks for plugging it into Mathematica.

Comment: @Moron: I'm not sure about constraints on a, b and c yet, since the probabilities are supposed to help me finding parameters for some algorithm. A closed form would be nice for the running time analysis of the algorithm, but maybe I can live without it.

Comment: @jug: So the sum you have is the runtime of some algorithm and you want to estimate it, i.e. a BigOh estimate will do? What are the variables? (I ask this based on your last sentence).

Comment: @Moron: This probability is only one term in a bigger sum, and it's too complicated to get into details about the variables. BigOh won't do.

Comment: jug: Would you mind posting the actual "bigger sum"?

Comment: @J.Mangaldan: Sorry for the late response; I found a different approach calculating the probabilities. I doubt the "bigger sum" would help as each summand has yet another coefficient. But if you are curious: The next bigger term has $(a+1)$ in the place of $a$, $b$ might be greater and the sum is starting at $(c+2)$.

Comment: @J.Mangaldan: Thanks for your interest. In the moment I'm content with Qiaochu Yuan's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have time right now to work out the exact answer, but the methods and identities in the middle third of [this blog post](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/blog.php?u=14052&b=10590) will give a closed form for fixed $a$.  Use the geometric series formula to find $\sum_{j=0}^c p^{a+b+j}$, differentiate $a$ times with respect to $p$, then divide by $a! p^b$.

If a closed form for fixed $a$ isn't good enough, you should probably be more precise about which of your parameters are large and which are small.

Edit:  Still don't have time to give a complete answer, but here's a fun trick.  Instead of computing the answer for fixed $a$ we can write down a generating function

$$\displaystyle P_{b,c}(x) = \sum_{a=0}^{\infty} x^a \sum_{j=0}^c {a+b+j \choose a} p^j$$

then exchange the order of summation, giving

$$\displaystyle \begin{align}
P_{b,c}(x) &= \sum_{j=0}^c p^j \sum_{a=0}^{\infty} {a+b+j \choose a} x^a \\
 &= \sum_{j=0}^c p^j \frac{1}{(1 - x)^{b+j+1}} \\
 &= \frac{1}{(1 - x)^{b+1}} \sum_{j=0}^c \left( \frac{p}{1-x} \right)^j \\
 &= \frac{1}{(1 - x)^{b+1}} \frac{1 - \left( \frac{p}{1-x} \right)^{c+1}}{1 - \frac{p}{1-x}} \\
 &= \frac{(1-x)^{c+1} - p^{c+1}}{(1 - x)^{b+c+1}(1 - p - x)}. \end{align}$$

Then the coefficient of $x^a$ of this rational function is the number you want.  Not sure how useful that is for you, but you might be able to extract a useful asymptotic from it.  The identity in the second line is the binomial theorem for negative exponents.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I'll check if I can get it working. Closed for fixed $a$ might be OK (not sure yet).

Comment: That's a great blog post.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need an exact closed form or just care about the asymptotic growth [Stirling's Approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) might be useful. I've found it useful in the past for generating good asymptotic bounds on similar functions.

Comment: If p is small then you should get a much better asymptotic just by taking c to infinity.  The dominant term here is the exponential, not its coefficient (which is merely polynomial).